# Magento2 show sku on message

Tags: magento2

I want to show product sku on preorder message that displays on cart page.
By default it shows the product name.
How can I change it to product sku?

Thankyou

Comment: You are using any third party extension for preorder?

Comment: No,Simple magento2 preorder message on cart page

Comment: Can you give screen-shot where it display.

Comment: Please check:  http://prntscr.com/fy2fyj